# awk does not read from pipe

Tags: bash, awk

I'm new to awk and shell script. 
When I execute this command:

```
~$ sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

It prints:

```
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01301|(
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|600020000008002018010000800000920000121947070700203231313030323832
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01311|)
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01301|(
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|600020000008002018010000800000920000121947070700203231313030323832
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01311|)

SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01311|)
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|600000002008102018010002800004920000122009070700203030323131303032383200340032307C6458EE3A4EF4C37D5BEBD6D609A1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01311|)
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01301|(
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|600000002008102018010002800004920000122009070700203030323131303032383200340032307C6458EE3A4EF4C37D5BEBD6D609A1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01311|)
```

When I execute:

```
~$ sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep --line-buffered "SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|"
```

It prints:

```
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|600020000008002018010000800000920000121546070700203231313030323832
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|600020000008002018010000800000920000121546070700203231313030323832
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|600000002008102018010002800004920000121603070700203030323131303032383200340032AE66FF30893AD0E4ABF1E6F6C17F229AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|600000002008102018010002800004920000121603070700203030323131303032383200340032AE66FF30893AD0E4ABF1E6F6C17F229AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

When I type:

```
~$ sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep --line-buffered "SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|" | uniq
```

It prints out:

```
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|600020000008002018010000800000920000104334070700203231313030323832
SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|60000000200810201801000280000492000010435107070020303032313130303238320034003228D4F55F51CBFF1D673D037DBBE5BADCFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

But when I execute:

```
~$ sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep --line-buffered "SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|" | uniq | awk ' {FS="|"; print $3;}'
```

It prints nothing.

Comment: What happens if you remove `uniq` from the pipeline?

Comment: @Jacob Krall: It's work properly. I can't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. /dev/ttyUSB0 doesn't send an Eof character. When I save message to a file and execute command:

```
sudo cat ./myfile | grep --line-buffered "SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|" | uniq | awk -F "|" '{print $3}'
```

It works!

Answer (score 2):

Your `awk` command should be:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $3}'
```

The way you have it, you're setting your field separator too late.

Alternatively, you could set it in a `BEGIN` block within the `awk` script, like so:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"}; {print $3}'
```

Or you could just use the `cut` command instead:

```
cut -d\| -f3
```

Comment: I applaud your suggestion to use `cut` rather than `awk`.

Comment: @JacobKrall `cut` just fits so well. Nice edit, BTW.

Comment: sorry you guys, my awk script is not good, but it works. I've try the following command and it still does not work: ~$ sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep --line-buffered "SOFTPAY:F:isoutl.c|L:01307|" | uniq | cut -d\| -f3

Comment: @user2767553 Your awk script won't work since it doesn't set the field separator until after it has read the first line, which is too late for it to split the fields with that separator. So it will screw up on the first line, although it will work for the rest of the lines. As for your problem, try running just the cat command, then the cat with the grep, then the cat with the grep with the uniq. Does each of those work properly?

Comment: That makes no sense. Try getting rid of the `--line-buffered` option.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `uniq` is waiting for `/dev/ttyUSB0` to either close or send more output.

Adam Batkin had this answer posted, but deleted it:

> The `uniq` command will only return output once it sees a line that is
>   different than the previous line. The exception is the final line (or
>   set of lines) which it will print at `EOF`. But if it doesn't get an
>   `EOF`, the last line (or set of lines) will never be printed.